# How to generate a professional table in LyX?

Tags: tables, lyx, booktabs

Many academic journals ask authors to make tables in a professional style, i.e., only have horizontal rules (usually 3 horizontal rules) without any vertical rules.

In LaTeX, the *booktabs* package could help to generate such tables.

In LyX, of course we can use the same way as using LaTeX, but I wonder if there exists a simpler solution.

Thanks a lot!

P.S.
I have tried the way mentioned in LyX wiki page ([Table formatting](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables#toc8)), but that was still not easy enough.

Comment: Hello. This is a nice question. I'm, however, afraid, that it is more a feature request for the `booktabs` authors to create the LyX stuff for the package. The problem is though that the package has not been updated since 2005, according to [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), and its author Simon Fear is not active as its maintainer. Still, you can try to contact Danie Els.

Comment: Actually I think it is more up to LyX to support booktabs. And it already does, since version 1.5.0. See Help > Embedded Objects. Search for "booktabs" or just go to the section titled "Formal Tables".

Comment: @scottkosty I have read the manual of LyX, but still feel that's not easy enough. Thank you all the same!

Comment: OK good to know. In that case if you have an idea for how to make it easy (e.g. what would you like to be able to do? Click on a check box option?), please write a feature request at http://www.lyx.org/trac . Please be as detailed as possible. Give 1. the LaTeX code that you would like to produce by using LyX and 2. the way in LyX that you would like to achieve this. This feedback would really help us.

Comment: I don't see how it is too difficult. Anyway, as it sounds like you're after an enhancement of LyX, there isn't really much we can do here. Those kinds of things are better dealt with in LyX' issue tracker, that @scottkosty mentioned in his comment.  For that reason, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Please comment if you disagree, questions can always be reopened if they're closed.